# Get userID in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to get the userId of the logged in user in ASP.net, I can use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

to get the name, but how do I get the userID?

I tried (GUID) and Membership.GetUser as I found, but none seem to work.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit like what exactly you are trying to get with an example?

Comment: I'm trying to get the userId of the logged in user, so I can get records for that user from the database.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [ProviderUserKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx) property.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've used it wrong, but I've tried this as I saw after googling and it didn't work.

Comment: What error or response do you get. This might be a stupid question, but do you even have Membership configured for your application?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
string userID = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

**Edit:**

You need to make sure you import the System.Web.Security class to use the MembershipUser class. In VB.Net you can do that like this:

**HTML**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

Comment: What is the result when you try this? Does it error? Is the result not the actual guid for the user?

Comment: Errors for MembershipUser, missing from assembly, Membership.GetUser, reference required to assembly, and user.ProviderUserKey, not a member of 'System.Security.Principle.IPrinciple

Comment: Are you importing System.Web.Security?

Comment: Sorry am new to VB, how do I import that?

Comment: Still can't use MembershipUser

Answer (score 0):

`Dim mu As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()`

`Dim strUsrId As String = mu.ProviderUserKey.ToString()`

Hope this helps.